# Power Automate PWA tasks to Planner tasks

Tags: power-automate

Using Power Automate I can move tasks from PWA to Planner but only until it reaches the next outdented task. How do I get all tasks (indented or not) to appear on my planner board?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ofresia

Comment: [See if this article can help](https://manueltgomes.com/reference/power-automate-action-reference/planner-list-tasks-action/).